# How to create a trigger in SQL Server that execute on a specific time and only once

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, asp.net-core-mvc

I want a trigger (or something like that) that when is a specific date, for example 01-01 (every year) to execute only once and add to every column +20.

Table: `Id#, Number`

I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC project and I want to be able to do this operation for my database.

Comment: You need a scheduled job not a trigger

Comment: Create a Job and Schedule it.

Comment: A **trigger** is triggered by a specific operation - an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. You **cannot** specifically execute a "trigger" at a time of your chosing - that's just the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in SQL Server Agent and select 'New Job'

In the 'New Job' window enter the name of the job and a description on the 'General' tab.

Select 'Steps' on the left hand side of the window and click 'New' at the bottom.

In the 'Steps' window enter a step name and select the database you want the query to run against.

Paste in the T-SQL command you want to run into the Command window and click 'OK'.

Click on the 'Schedule' menu on the left of the New Job window and enter the schedule information (e.g. daily and a time).

Click 'OK' - and that should be it.

(There are of course other options you can add - but I would say that is the bare minimum you need to get a job set up and scheduled)

Answer (score 0):

Quartz.net scheduler can be helpful for the purpose.

ISimpleTrigger trigger = (ISimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder.Create() .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1") .StartAt(myStartTime) // some Date .ForJob("job1", "group1") // identify job with name, group strings .Build();